# video face detection using dlib

Tags: c++, video, face-detection, dlib

I am trying to make a offline video face detection program. I have used the example code for face detection and it is working good. But since the dlib library doesn't work directly on video(or I don't know if it does), I am providing frames to the image face detection program. For a small video such as 20-30 frame video it is working fine, but if given a bigger video it is having buffer overflow error. Do I have to remove data or clear some dynamic memory explicitly? Or does it only handle few images for face detection?

Below is the code snippet

```
// Loop over all the images provided on the command line.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 629; ++i)
    {
        //cout << "processing image " << endl;
        array2d<unsigned char> img;
        //load_image(img, argv[i]);
    sprintf(image, "./frame/frame%d.jpg",i);
    load_image(img, image);

        pyramid_up(img);

        // Now tell the face detector to give us a list of bounding boxes
        // around all the faces it can find in the image.
        std::vector<rectangle> dets = detector(img);

        //cout << "Number of faces detected: " << dets.size() << endl;
    //cout<<i<<"\t"<<dets.size()<<endl;
        // Now we show the image on the screen and the face detections as
        // red overlay boxes.
        win.clear_overlay();
        win.set_image(img);
        win.add_overlay(dets, rgb_pixel(255,0,0));

        //cout << "Hit enter to process the next image..." << endl;
        //cin.get();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Dlib has an OpenCV integration for that. You can read video file with OpenCV functions and use Dlib for face detection

Here is a sample on such kind of integration

http://dlib.net/webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.html

You should only change

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
```

into

```
cv::VideoCapture videoCapture;
videoCapture.open(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your frames are big, then detection will be slow. So it would be better to resize your frames and then perform the tracking/detection process.